# Javascript animate math

Tags: javascript, math, animation

I'm struggling to get my head around such simple Math, well at least it seems it should be simple.

I'm basically trying to mirror what jQuery's `.animate` does, but to no luck.

Here's a simplified version of what I have so far:

```
var args = {
  speed: 1000, // 1 second.
  left: 65 // distance.
}, rot, step;

// Terrible math.
rot = step = (((args.left / args.speed) * 10) - 0.10);

var t = setInterval(function() {
  if(elem.style.left >= args.left) {
    clearInterval(t);
    return;
  }
  rot += step;
  elem.style.left = rot;
}, 10);
```

Please excuse any illogical code (or math), I've been messing around for a good few hours and totally lost my sanity.

Comment: Why are you multiplying with 10 and subtracting with 0.10 I think you are using  distance / time  will give you the step

Comment: Can you share your example input and expected out put also

Comment: @aravind.udayashankara I think also the issue is you have to account for the interval times, though, my method is undoubtably wrong.

Comment: Okay Now I got It you are trying to rotate an object based on the distance input In X and Y coordinate am I correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

Here's the way I would do it.

```
var start_time = Date.now();
// Get the starting time in milliseconds

var t = setInterval(function() {

    var delta_time = Date.now() - start_time;
    // Get time that has elapsed since starting

    if (delta_time >= 1000) {
        // if it's been a second

        clearInterval(t);
        // Stop the timer

        elem.style.left = args.left + 'px';
        // Set the element to exactly the value it should be (avoids having it set to a float value)

        return;
    }

    elem.style.left = delta_time * args.left / args.speed + 'px';
    // Move the element according to how much time has elapsed

}, 10);​
```

This method has a few advantages. For example, you can adjust the interval to make it more or less smooth, and it won't mess up the animation.

The reason why your solution was taking longer than one second is because of how you used `setInterval`. `setInterval` doesn't account for the time your code takes to run, so the total time is always increased by a bit. You can fix this by using delta timing (like in my example).

Comment: Nope, that's not the problem. The issue is the math, any flaws in the code other than the math can be ignored.

Comment: That is because you are still not updating the element's position using delta time. Have a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/grc4/WD7dq/

Comment: Sorry, I commented on the wrong answer, i'll give this a shot, it certainly looks good.

Comment: Any ideas how to reverse the process? (mouseout)

Comment: Well, initially this is for a mouseover event, I'm trying to work out how exactly to reverse the process for a mouseout. Quite tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Well for one it should be

```
var args = { ... }
```

assuming you have the elem set up correctly, you're going to need a inline styling of the attribute you want to animate. Also, you're going to need to parse the style since it has the 'px' attached to it, but you can always add that after you do the math within the interval function.

I set up something here so you can mess around with the settings and whatnot.

edit:
http://jsfiddle.net/mb4JA/2/

edit2:
this should be one second
http://jsfiddle.net/mb4JA/4/

final answer ;) http://jsfiddle.net/mb4JA/10/

You should be able to put any speed in there, and have it animate for that amount of seconds.

Comment: Yeah, ignore any errors in the code like that. I'm really looking for the mathematical logic, your example didn't really do much.

Comment: Should be a smooth slide in the new link. I think your math was fine

Answer (score 0):

Try using useing sin and cos to calculate rotation Some what like this

```
newx = distance * Math.cos(direction) + x
newy = distance * Math.sin(direction) + y
```

Not sure , this will solve your problem I guess you want to to do a smooth rotation

Try making it as a function it will work , I am not seeing any problem in your math ,

like this

```
function move(elem) {

var left = 0

function frame() {

left++  // update parameters

elem.style.left = left  // show frame

if (left == 100)  // check finish condition
clearInterval(id)
}

var id = setInterval(frame, 10) // draw every 10ms
}
```

Comment: I am doing rotations, but the math should be the same for manipulating the `left` style.

Comment: I just updated my answer , Can you try I am not seeing any problem with your math , The only defect I saw is the way you are returning from setInterval function , I Updated a function similar to yours try using it with your args variable